# How do I pass variables to a buttons event method?

Tags: c#, events

I need to be able to pass along two objects to the method being fired when I click a button. How do I do this?

So far I've been looking at creating a changed `EventArgs`:

```
 public class CompArgs : System.EventArgs
    {
    private object metode;
    private Type typen;

    public CompArgs(object m, Type t)
    {
        this.metode = m;
        this.typen = t;
    }

    public object Metode()
    {
        return metode;
    }

    public Type Typen()
    {
        return typen;
    }
}
```

But how would I use it? Is it possible to somehow override the click-event of the button to use a custom `eventhandler`, which takes `CompArgs` as a parameter?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\components.dll");

            int counter = 0;
            
            foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
            {
                if (type.IsClass == true)
                {

                    Button btn = new Button();
                    btn.Location = new Point(174 + (counter * 100),10);
                    btn.Size = new Size(95, 23);
                    btn.Name = type.Name;
                    btn.Text = type.Name;
                    btn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                    

                    this.Controls.Add(btn);

                    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

                    //I need to pass on obj and type to the btn_Click
                    btn.Click += new eventHandler(btn_Click);

                    counter++;
                }
            }
         }
```

And the event-method where I need it:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, CompArgs ca)
        {
                MessageBox.Show((string)ca.Typen().InvokeMember("getMyName",
                             BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                             null,
                             ca.Metode(),
                             null));

        }
```

Comment: You can override the OnClick method by deriving from the Button class. Have added an answer using this technique.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cant you just set a property or member variable on the form that hosts the button and access these from the button click event?

EDIT: custom button class suggestion after feedback comment (not the same suggestion as above)

```
class MyButton : Button
{
    private Type m_TYpe;

    private object m_Object;

    public object Object
    {
        get { return m_Object; }
        set { m_Object = value; }
    }

    public Type TYpe
    {
        get { return m_TYpe; }
        set { m_TYpe = value; }
    }
}




Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  MyButton mb = (sender as MyButton);

  //then you can access Mb.Type
  //and  Mb.object
}
```

Comment: @WraithNath - I've used this approach before, but feel it is kind of an unclean way to do it. I need the button to reference the right objects so the way i did it last time was to store the objects in a list. Saved the relative index of a buttons object in its Tag property and then parsed it when i needed it.

Comment: Hi, Where is the information coming from that you want to pass into the click event? does it exist inside the button control already on on the form? I think the only way to be able to change the button click handler is to implement your own button control or a derivative of the windows forms one. You could store the objects you want to use in the click event in the tag of the button as an array or a custom type then just cast the sender as a button and retrieve the tag. Is the button on a popup form where the user selects and option and closes the form?

Comment: @WraithNath - I've included some more code. The concept you describe is how i've handled it earlier. But as i said, it feels a bit.. unclean.

Comment: ah, then I would recommend Matthew Steeples approach, you could create a custom button that exposes the properties and objects you need. I have edited my answer to show an example

Comment: @WraithNath - this looks like a nice uncomplicated approach.

Answer (score 79):

Wow, you guys are making this entirely to difficult.  No need for any custom classes or method overrides. In this example I just need to pass a tab index number. You can specify whatever you want, so long as your method is expecting that value type.

```
button.Click += (sender, EventArgs) => { buttonNext_Click(sender, EventArgs, item.NextTabIndex); };

void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, int index)
    {
       //your code
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why people are not just using this answer. So much simpler.

Comment: Far more elegant and lean than deriving from the control class.

Comment: Hey guys, I know this is an older post but I thought I would point out that if the you plop a variable in the code above VS will throw a fit. I have a button that I wanted to send a switcher on keypress, I used the above code (which is great) but it didnt like the boolean variable ... this is the method signature: `private void UpdateDBButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, bool fullReset)` and the event handler line: `UpdateDBButton.Click += (sender, EventArgs) => { bool fullReset = false; UpdateDBButton_Click(sender, EventArgs, fullReset); };`

Comment: @Jesse Fender Be sure to pass in the equal arguments. You need to pass sender, EventArgs, then boolean

Comment: @RudyHinojosa I believe that snippet I posted in the my comment does that, the `(sender, EventArgs)` are passed, with the addition of in this case a boolean to the event handler. It works, I have it in a production application and in this case it was a flag that helped determine how to handle the update of the database tables dropping remotely filled ones and leaving supplemental ones, or removing all the tables and starting them over with a fresh remote db pull... It took me hours to find how to write the code, so I thought it may help some one else with their search in the future. Cheers!

Comment: @RudyHinojosa - NICE WORK! very compact and elegant! *** Bildsoe, please change this to be the ANSWER ***

Comment: When I use this method I get the error: "No overload for 'ButtonProduction_Click' matches delegate 'RoutedEventHandler'"
Here's my code:

ButtonProduction.Click += (sender, EventArgs) => { ButtonProduction_Click(sender, EventArgs, "test"); };

private void ButtonProduction_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, string test)
        {
        }

Comment: @DouglasPlumley Make sure the argument types match. You are passing EventArgs as the second parameter, and the method is expecting RoutedEventArgs.  Change RoutedEventArgs to EventArgs

Comment: @RudyHinojosa Doesn't seem to make a difference in my solution, still has the same error.  This is my first foray into C#/WPF, it's probably something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @RudyHinojosa - I was able to work around it by defining a new method that's not referenced as the button click event in the XAML code. Perhaps this is what you originally intended?

<Button x:Name="ButtonProduction" Click="ButtonProduction_Click"/>

ButtonProduction.Click += (sender, EventArgs) => { prodButton_Click(sender, EventArgs, "test"); };

private void prodButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, string s)
{
 MessageBox.Show(s);
}

private void ButtonProduction_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
}

Comment: @DouglasPlumley Oh good. I wasn't sure if WPF handled things a bit differently, but thanks for adding the solution for that model. Cheers!

Comment: Man! This is awesome! Simple, professional and helpful! Many thanks!

Comment: how can we remove this event from click. I am having button in listview object. so I want to do something like this                                                                                 button.Click += (sender, EventArgs) => { buttonNext_Click(sender, EventArgs, item.NextTabIndex); };                      &&                                                     button.Click -= (sender, EventArgs) => { buttonNext_Click(sender, EventArgs, item.NextTabIndex); };                                                                                                                how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the button. You can add a string value to this property from the designer properties window and then pick it up within the handler as so:

```
    private void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string tagValue = ((Button) sender).Tag;

        if(tag == "blah")
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd create a new Button and override the OnClick method. Rather than passing down the EventArgs, pass a new derived class in with your additional members.

On the delegate receiving the event, cast the given EventArgs to the more derived class you're expecting to get, alternatively setup a new Event that will be triggered at the same time when the button is pressed and hook up to that instead to make things more implicit.

Example Code:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ButtonEx b1 = new ButtonEx();
        b1.OnCustomClickEvent += new ButtonEx.OnCustomClickEventHandler(b1_OnCustomClickEvent);
    }

    void  b1_OnCustomClickEvent(object sender, ButtonEx.CustomEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        string p1 = eventArgs.CustomProperty1;
        string p2 = eventArgs.CustomProperty2;
    }
}

public class ButtonEx : Button
{
    public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public String CustomProperty1;
        public String CustomProperty2;
    }

    protected override void  OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
        if(OnCustomClickEvent != null)
        {
            OnCustomClickEvent(this, new CustomEventArgs());
        }
    }

    public event OnCustomClickEventHandler OnCustomClickEvent;
    public delegate void OnCustomClickEventHandler(object sender , CustomEventArgs eventArgs);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use your own custom event argument class for a predefined event handler signature. At least, the custom event argument type will never be utilised by any default calls to the handler (which will only ever be of type `EventArgs` in the case of a button); you could, potentially, call the handler yourself, passing your custom type, however, you would need to have logic in order to cast it back from an `EventArgs` into that which it had been cast from.

As a possible solution (depending on your situation), consider a composite type to encapsulate the items you require, as with your event argument type, but keep the required instance as an accessible variable which can be utilised from within the event handler, or, at least, by the method/s which the even handler invokes.

For example, define your type...

```
public class MyType
{
    public object AccessibleItem { get; set; }
}
```

And, in your form class...

```
private MyType MyTypeInstance = new MyType();

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //here we can set the item, if needs be...
    MyTypeInstance.AccessibleItem = new Anything();
    //or access the item to use as required...
    DoSomeMagicWithMyObject(MyTypeInstance.AccessibleItem);
}
```

EDIT:

Okay, looking at your current code I can only offer you this for now (it doesn't add the items to the forms control container and it uses a variable iterator within Linq (which I think is either frowned upon or just down-right wrong (?), but hey...):

```
    private void BuildButtonToObjectDictionary()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\components.dll");

        var buttonToObjectDictionary = (
            from type in assembly.GetTypes()
            where type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract
            select new
            {
                Button = new Button
                {
                    Name = type.Name,
                    Text = type.Name,
                    Size = new Size(95, 25),
                    Location = new Point(175 + (counter * 100), 10),
                    UseVisualStyleBackColor = true
                },
                Item = Activator.CreateInstance(type),
                Index = counter++
            });
    }
```

Comment: But i will have alot of buttons with their own objects needing to be accessed. How can i do this. Earlier i stored the objects in a list. Saved the relative index of a buttons object in its Tag property and then parsed it when i needed it.

Comment: @Bildsoe: Where are the instances created? IT's the same kind of concept, but you could use a `Dictionary`, whereby the `Key` a reference to a button and is associated with the appropriate `Value` - or even a `Hashtable`.

Comment: I've include some more code to show you what i'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think you've gone down the wrong approach. Using Reflection to solve this simple problem isn't right...

Comment: @Ian - How would you go about it then? My idea was to create a way to extend my app by making it dynamically read assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this exists in Winforms but it does in WPF: There is a "tag" object on all controls which you can attach any object to. You could save the object that you want to pass and then in the event handler read it back out of the sender object.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var note = (sender as FrameworkElement).Tag as Note;
    //Do something with note here
}
```

Comment: It's not a very elegant way though. You have to know about the Tag and what to expect in it.

Answer (score 0):

Would need to see more code to give a better answer, but you could create an event that takes your CompArgs as a parameter and is fired when the buttonEvent is captured

Answer (score 0):

If you open yourForm.Designer.cs file you will see all the code auto generated by VS. Here you can alter the method called when clicking on the button (or add a second method).

```
this.yourButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(211, 51);
this.yourButton.Name = "yourButton";
this.yourButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
this.yourButton.TabIndex = 0;
this.yourButton.Text = "yourButton";
this.yourButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
this.yourButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.yourMethodHere(object1, object2);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: is this possible? isn't the sender and the eventArgs allways passed as parameters?

Comment: As far as I can see, this will not work at all. And even if it did, it would always be the same two arguments specified as parameters, rather than being called and the arguments specified per invocation. And if that happened to be the desired behaviour, it still wouldn't compile, due to the missing parenthesis.