# How to call Button OnCLick eventhandler in code behind with a value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create Anchors in code behind and delete buttons as well for each Anchor. I dont know if i can call an event handler for each one of the link with an ID so i can delete the row specified from the database. This is what i have done. I created an anchor and an ASp button but not sure how i can call it with that ImageID. Is it possible? If so How? Thanks a lot in advance!!  This is in C#, asp.net.

```
 HtmlAnchor apdf = new HtmlAnchor();
 apdf.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
 string ImageID = "";
 if (dsreport != null && dsreport.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
 {
      apdf.InnerText = dsreport.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ImageName"].ToString();
      apdf.Attributes.Add("style", "font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px; margin: 0px;    font-family: Arial; color: #1e7c9b; text-decoration: underline");
      apdf.Target = "_blank";
      ImageSalesID = dsreport.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ImageID"].ToString();
      apdf.HRef = "PDFdownload.aspx?ID=" + ImageID;

 }   
 Button btnDelete = new Button();
 btnDelete.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
 btnDelete.OnClick += Eventhandler;
 btnDelete.Text = "Delete";
```

Comment: not sure exactly what you asking but you can know what button is cliked by reading the id of the clicked button

Comment: Don't create these in code behind.  Use a Repeater and create a Command button and use the Repeater.ItemCommand and set the CommandArgument instead.  It's cleaner, uses less code, is more standard, and easier. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx  (Or use a DataList if you prefer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this may help you in some way

```
 Button btnDelete = new Button();
    btnDelete.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);

    protected void button_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        string buttonid = button.ID.ToString()
        // identify which button was what row to update based on id clicked and perform necessary actions
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! It helps me go half way. Is it possible to send something in new EventHandler(button_Click) like an ImageID or something??

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815629/how-do-i-pass-variables-to-a-buttons-event-method

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, you're pressing a button, and then wanting to delete something that's related to said button; if this is the case I would recommend using the `CommandArgument` property on a button. You can also specify the `CommandName` as well which can assist in determine what type of action to occur. Here's a quick example:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteRow" CommandArgument="1" Text="Delete Row 1" OnClick="DeleteRow" />
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteRow" CommandArgument="2" Text="Delete Row 2" OnClick="DeleteRow" />
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteRow" CommandArgument="3" Text="Delete Row 3" OnClick="DeleteRow" />
```

All 3 buttons will trigger the same event. Then within the actual event itself you can check what the command arguments were on the sender, by casting it as a `Button`, like so.

```
protected void DeleteRow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var buttonClicked = sender as Button;
    var rowId = buttonClicked.CommandArgument;
    var action = buttonClicked.CommandName;

    // do something depending on the action and the argument
}
```

Hope this helps. :)