# asp.et adding onclick to a button programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I know this question has been asked many times, but I read the answers for other questions and my code still gives me an error

This is my code

```
Button loadButton = new Button();
                loadButton.Text = "Load";
                loadButton.Click += new EventHandler(this.openOutlook());

private void openOutlook()
        {}
```

now I got error states `method names expected` on this line `new EventHandler(this.openOutlook());`

I tried to add `object sender, EventsArg arg` to the header of the method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call Button OnCLick eventhandler in code behind with a value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218523/how-to-call-button-onclick-eventhandler-in-code-behind-with-a-value)

Comment: You have 2 problems: 1) Your `openOutlook` method does not have the signature of `openOutlook(object sender, EventArgs e)` and when you invoke the method in your event handler, you need to ditch the brackets, since you are passing a function pointer (delegate).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly new up the EventHandler - if the target handler method has the appropriate signature, you can add the subscription directly:

```
loadButton.Click += openOutlook;

private void openOutlook(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Button loadButton = new Button();
loadButton.Text = "Load";
loadButton.Click += new EventHandler(btnOk_Click);
void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

When intellisence showing the click event name on button object, press the tab key twice if ur using Visual Studio IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new EventHandler(this.openOutlook);
```

without parenthesis. Your event handler expects just method name.

and for your method

```
openOutlook(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
```

Comment: method also required `object sender, EventsArg arg` parameters.

Comment: Please check question as accepted if it helped you.