# No overload matches delegate EventHandler, even though arguments in handler method seem fine

Tags: c#, .net, eventhandler

I'm very much a beginning programmer, trying to grasp the details of event handling. And I'm breaking my head over a problem. See below:

```
public class Knop_ClickEventArgs : System.EventArgs
{
  //Here comes code that still needs to be written.
}

static void Knop_Click(object sender, Knop_ClickEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    Application.Run(canvas);
}

public PromptScherm()
{
    //Deleted some code here that is most likely uninteresting

    Button Knop = new Button();

    // Deleted uninteresting code here as well

    this.Controls.Add(Knop);

    Knop.Click += Knop_Click;

}
```

This (shortened) piece of code gives the `CS0123` error, describing that my `Knop_Click` method does not match the delegate `EventHandler`.

I've pinpointed that the problem is with the `Knop_ClickEventArgs`, because if I replace that with `System.EventArgs` it works fine. However, since I specify in the definition of `Knop_ClickEventArgs` that it is a specific instance of `System.EventArgs`, it puzzles me why that would cause a problem?

Comment: `Click` handler should be able to handle every possible `EventArgs`, but your `Knop_Click` can only handle `Knop_ClickEventArgs`.

Comment: EventArgs instance cannot be converted to Knop_ClickEventArgs implicitly. Probably you need to inherit button and override click for custom event args support. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815629/how-do-i-pass-variables-to-a-buttons-event-method for more info

Comment: are you using winforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting it all wrong. you just need a appropriate event handler attached to Click event.

```
static void Knop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
// ...
Knop.Click += Knop_Click;
```

Now this method will be called when Button fires Click event. you can not change signature because that's how button fires this event. something like this.

```
Click.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); // "this" refers to button it self.
```

Now in `Knop_Click` you receive arguments that Button has just passed to.

```
static void Knop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    // do some logic.
}
```

Now what do you expect to happen if you change signature? what you want cant be achieved because EventArgs is base class, and Button is passing EventArgs, it cant be converted to your derived class.

You must clarify what your goal is. clarify what code needs to be written, so we can suggest right place for it

Answer (score 2):

When you add a handler to the `Click` event of a control, (in this case, a `Button` that you call `Knop`,) the `Button` will be invoking your handler passing it `object sender, System.EventArgs e`.  This means that:

- it is impossible to define your handler as accepting your own event class instead of `System.EventArgs`,
- If the compiler allowed you to do so, you would be in real trouble, because `Button` would still be passing a `System.EventArgs` to your handler, completely ignoring your wishes to receive something else instead.

Your plan to add code to your event class tells me that perhaps there is something you have not understood about events and event-passing.  Events are supposed to carry data, they are not supposed to contain code.