# c# windows forms passing values from initialize to button click

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I am trying to pass values from one form to another, and am able to successfully do so, but I am unable to get the passed values into a button press event on the second form. For example, in the button press on the first form I use the following code:

```
 Username = Usertxt.Text;
 Password = Passtxt.Text;
 Form2 f1 = new Form2(Username, Password);
 this.Hide();
 f1.Show();
```

On the second form I use:

```
public Form2(string Username, string Password)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

However, I can not figure out how to get the passed values into a button click event on the second form. I'm sure the solution is simple, but I haven't been able to find anything explaining this specific problem. If I am going in the wrong direction in general for passing variables between forms, please let me know, I am very new to c# and windows forms.

Comment: Do you know what a "*field*" is? take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields

Comment: Not sure about the duplicates, but this might be relevant as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815629/how-do-i-pass-variables-to-a-buttons-event-method

Comment: See my two form project answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net